# Last 3 months average next to current month value in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table which has the monthly sales values for each of the items. I need last 3 months average sales value next to the current month sales for each item.

Need to perform this operation in hive.

The sample input table looks like below

```
Item_ID Sales   Month
A   4295    Dec-2018
A   245     Nov-2018
A   1337    Oct-2018
A   3290    Sep-2018
A   2000    Aug-2018
B   856     Dec-2018
B   1694    Nov-2018
B   4286    Oct-2018
B   2780    Sep-2018
B   3100    Aug-2018
```

The result table should look like this

```
Item_ID Sales_Current_Month     Month           Sales_Last_3_months_average
A           4295                Dec-2018        1624
A           245                 Nov-2018        2209
B           856                 Dec-2018        2920
B          1694                 Nov-2018        3388.67
```

Comment: can you include your attempts as well? also clarify if the current month should be included for last 3 months average?

Comment: The last 3 months average does not include the current month. Sorry, still stuck in formulating a logic. I am yet to come up with an attempt that works.

Comment: doesn't matter even if your attempt has errors. you should always include it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no missing months data, you can use `avg` window function to do this.

```
select t.* 
      ,avg(sales) over(partition by item_id order by month rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) as avg_sales_prev_3_months
from tbl t
```

If `month` column is in a format different from `yyyyMM`, use an appropriate conversion so the ordering works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Vamsi for the query. The query runs but give weird results. Is there a requirement to have the table sorted in specific order of item_id and/or month before the above query is applied?

Comment: I think the problem can be in "3 preceding and 1 preceding", one of these should be current row. I have found the alternate way,slightly longer by calculating the sum of rows between current row and 3 following, then subtracting the current value and then dividing by 3 to get the desired average. However, now I face issues with Item_IDs having missing months